# Uploading multiple images with crop images in codeigniter, but getting too much time & giving errors of $_FILES.. but working fine for low size images

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am uploading images using codeigniter:

1) path//uploads/Property/.. (original image)

2) path/uploads/Property/100X100/.. (cropped image)

3) path/uploads/Property/300X300/.. (cropped image)

My Code Snippet:

```
public function photoform(){

$cpt="";

$prp_id=$this->session->userdata('main_prop_id');
$user_email =$this->session->userdata('email');

if($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != ""){

$allowed =  array('jpg','jpeg' ,'gif','png');
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $testimg =$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];

      $ppfilename = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_\w]+/", "", $testimg).".".$ext;

      $ppfilename = $ppfilename;
      $ppfilename = explode(".", $ppfilename);
      $ppnew_filename = "ad_" . $ppfilename[0] . time() . "." . $ppfilename[1];

      $ppthumb = explode(".", $ppnew_filename);
      $ppthumb = $ppthumb[0] . "_thumb". "." . $ppthumb[1];

      $_FILES["userfile"]["name"] = $ppnew_filename;
      $this->load->library("upload");

      $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options()); 

      if($this->upload->do_upload()){
          $ppimagedata = $this -> upload -> data();
          $ppnewimagename = $ppimagedata["file_name"];

          $this -> load -> library("image_lib");
          $config['image_library']   = 'gd2';
          $config['source_image']    = $ppimagedata["full_path"];
          $config['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
          $config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
          $config['new_image']       = './uploads/Property/100X100/';
          $config['width']           = 100;
          $config['height']          = 100;

          $this -> image_lib -> initialize($config);
          $this -> image_lib -> resize();

          $config['new_image']    = './uploads/Property/300X300/';
          $config['width']       = 300;
          $config['height']       = 300;
          $this -> image_lib -> initialize($config);
          $this -> image_lib -> resize();          
           }
        }
        else{
          $ppnewimagename = "";
          $ppthumb = "";
        }

          $room_id = $this->input->post('roomid');

          $where = array('room_id'=>$room_id,'prop_id' => $prp_id,'user'=>$user_email);

           $arr3 =   array(
               'image_name' => $ppnewimagename,
               'image_thumb' => $ppthumb,

              );        

        $insert_id = $this->home->updateTable('ci_room_details',$arr3,$where);

        $arr_f = array(
                  'property_id_fk' => $prp_id,
                  'image_name' => $ppnewimagename,
                  'image_thumb' => $ppthumb,
                  'room_id'=>$_POST['roomid'],
                  'entity_type_id_fk'=>$_POST['entity_type_id'],
                  'sub_entity_type_id_fk'=>$_POST['sub_entity_type_id']
              );

        $insert_id_f = $this->home->insertIntoTable('ci_property_images',$arr_f); 

    $cpt = count($_FILES['images']['name']);

    if($cpt > 0){

      $img = array();

      for($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i++) {
        if($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] == ""){
          unset($_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);
          unset($_FILES['images']['type'][$i]);
          unset($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i]);
          unset($_FILES['images']['error'][$i]);
          unset($_FILES['images']['size'][$i]);
        }
      }

      $cpt = count($_FILES['images']['name']);

      for($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i++) {
      if(isset($_FILES['images']['name'][$i])){
        if($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] != ""){

        $filename = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];         
        $ext1 = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $ranstr=random_string('alnum', 3);
        $new_filename = time() .$ranstr. "." . $ext1;       
        $thumb = time() . $ranstr. "_thumb." . $ext1;

        $_FILES['imag']['name']     = $new_filename;
        $_FILES['imag']['type']     = $_FILES['images']['type'] [$i];
        $_FILES['imag']['tmp_name']   = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] [$i];
        $_FILES['imag']['error']     = $_FILES ['images']['error'] [$i];
        $_FILES['imag']['size']     = $_FILES ['images']['size'] [$i];

        $this->upload->initialize ( $this->set_upload_options());
        if($this->upload->do_upload ('imag')){

          $imagedata = $this -> upload -> data();
          $newimagename = $imagedata["file_name"];
          //100x100 resize thumb
          $this -> load -> library("image_lib");
          $config['image_library']  = 'gd2';
          $config['source_image']   = $imagedata["full_path"];
          $config['create_thumb']   = TRUE;
          $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
          $config['new_image']      = './uploads/Property/100X100/';
          $config['width']          = 100;
          $config['height']         = 100;
          $this -> image_lib -> initialize($config);
          $this -> image_lib -> resize();
          //300x300 resize img
          $config['source_image']   = $imagedata["full_path"];
          $config['create_thumb']   = TRUE;
          $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
          $config['new_image']    = './uploads/Property/300X300/';
          $config['width']       = 300;
          $config['height']       = 300;
          $this -> image_lib -> initialize($config);
          $this -> image_lib -> resize();          
        }        
        unset($_FILES['imag']);

        $img[] = array(
            'image_name' => $new_filename,
            'image_thumb' => $thumb
          );
      }
      }// end if

    } // end for

    }
    else{
      $img[] = array(

            'image_name' => "",
            'image_thumb' => ""
          );
    }

   $img_cnt=count($img);

      if($img_cnt > 0){
        for($i = 0; $i < $img_cnt; $i++) {

          $arr3 = array(
              'property_id_fk' => $prp_id,
                'image_name' => $img[$i]['image_name'],
                  'image_thumb' => $img[$i]['image_thumb'],
                  'room_id'=>$_POST['roomid'],
                  'entity_type_id_fk'=>$_POST['entity_type_id'],
                 'sub_entity_type_id_fk'=>$_POST['sub_entity_type_id']
              );

         $insert_id1 = $this->home->insertIntoTable('ci_property_images',$arr3);         
        }
      }

       if($insert_id!=""){

        echo $room_id;

       }else{
          echo "";
       }

  exit;
}
```

Working fine for low size images, but giving problem during high size image uploading.. due to much time to upload mozilla gives $_FILES['userfile']['..'] (undefined index error, but work properly low size images) & chrome alerts to kill operation.

I am offering to upload 5 images at time means 15 images (including crop images)

please suggest the changes in above code.. how can i speed up the upload process??

Answer (score 0):

The default values for PHP will restrict you to a maximum `2 MB` upload file size. So to upload a file more than `2 MB` you need to set the value of:

`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 10M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 10M
```

and than restart your server to apply these settings.

Comment: how can i set it for codeigniter (is there any setting in cpanel or what?)

Comment: Check in your server `php.ini` config file

Comment: yes.. working fine for mozilla (but taking too much time) & also working fine for chrome, but chrome giving regular alerts during upload process (alerts of unresponsive page, ask to WAIT OR KILL).. I am choosing to wait then it works.. but how can prevent that chrome alert (of unresponsive)

Comment: That's the default behavior, It's better to limit the image size as some users are using slow internet, and they are not able to upload in that case.

Comment: Is there any idea to speed up image uploading?